# Where i can learn about openstack and cloud computing

Tags: cloud, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

Where i can learn about openstack and cloud computing
Sites with proper courses and video tutorials will be prefered and i have no knowledge about them.

Comment: http://openstack-in-production.blogspot.com/  The CERN OpenStack blog is a personal favorite.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that only way to learn about openstack is getting your hands dirty with it.
Try to install single node Openstack devstack setup (which is a cake walk, google it). With this setup, learn what all can you do with this powerful Openstack, then install multinode Openstack setup which will give you a very good understanding of basic working flow.
Go through  [this](https://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-ubuntu/glance-install.html) official Openstack documentation for multi-node setup

In order to get a good understanding of networking involved follow this link: https://blogs.oracle.com/ronen/entry/diving_into_openstack_network_architecture

For anyother openstack related doubt just post your queries in https://ask.openstack.org

Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenStack Marketplace itself allows you to search for training to suit your needs and level.
http://www.openstack.org/marketplace/training/

A few other sources for cloud / openstack training include sites such as:

- https://linuxacademy.com/openstack
- http://opencloudacademy.rackspace.com/

Hope that helps get you started.

For self-study, you can also check out the many resources at O'Reilly which has books, webcasts, and also some video learning paths:
http://search.oreilly.com/?q=openstack&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 1):

For the OpenStack it is definitely http://www.openstack.org/ and its docs, and marketplace for distros https://www.openstack.org/marketplace/distros/
Similar to Hadoop, while it is free and open source it is hard to start, and most companies go with specific Hadoop distribution. So is with OpenStack to many ways to start. Find distro that you sympathize with.

But for cloud computing in general (especially good quality videos) is not so straight forward. I would recommend general online courses from MIT, Vanderbilt, Stanford etc available directly or via https://www.coursera.org/ and the like MOOCs.

These would be quite different aproaches, but I would recommend to use them in the same time. Some latest university/theoretics and real de-facto standard for cloud platfrom.